System.Net.CookieException: the domain part of the cookie is invalid
In ASP.NET MVC (on .NET 4.8), I am getting the following error:

System.Net.CookieException: the domain part of the cookie is invalid

The error occurs in the following function:
private CookieContainer AddCookiesToRequest()
{
    var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    var cookieDomain = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority).Split('.')[1];
    var cookies = this.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Request.Cookies;

    _logger.Info($"Cookie domain set to: {cookieDomain}");
    _logger.Info($"Cookies found in base controller: {string.Join(" , ", cookies?.Select(x => $"[{x.Key}] = {x.Value}"))}");

    foreach (var cookie in cookies)
    {
        var cook = new Cookie(cookie.Key, cookie.Value, null, cookieDomain);
        cookieContainer.Add(cook);
    }

    return cookieContainer;
}

The cookieDomain variable's value is https://uat1.abc.com and the error message is this one:

System.Net.CookieException: the 'Domain'='https://uat1.abc.com' part of the cookie is invalid.

I am guessing that, when the new instance of the cookie is added to the cookie container, the cookieDomain variable is set wrong.
Thanks

Are you absolutely sure that is the value of cookieDomain here? It should definitely not contain the https:// part

Yes, I can see that from the log file.

Try to get cookieDomain by the following
var uri = new Uri(Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority));
var cookieDomain = uri.Host;

